# I tried to use zeep library to make SOAP reuests and had trouble with ImportError:

Tags: python, soap, importerror, zeep, xmlsec

```
>>> from zeep import Client
>>> from zeep.wsse.signature import Signature
>>> client = Client(
...     'http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertSpeed.asmx?WSDL',
...     wsse=Signature(
...         private_key_filename, public_key_filename,
...         optional_password))
```

I ran the code based on this official sample code above.
However, I got this error below.

```
ImportError: The xmlsec module is required for wsse.Signature()
You can install xmlsec with: pip install xmlsec
or install zeep via: pip install zeep[xmlsec]
```

But, I've already installed that.

#### Edit:

When I put just `import xmlsec` I got this error below:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2):
  Symbol not found: _xmlSecDSigNs
  Referenced from: /Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace in /Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

Comment: Are you using a venv? If so, did you install the module inside the venv as well? Did you use said command to install?

Comment: You may also have multiple installations of Python - `pip install xmlsec` did install the package for one version (e.g. 2.7), while `python` starts an interactive shell in another (e.g. Python 3).

Comment: When I put just
 import xmlsec
 I got this error below:
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _xmlSecDSigNs
  Referenced from: /Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/myaccount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so

Comment: @hoefling
 I checked python's version by using sys. It said 3.8.5 and xmlsec is in /Users/myacount/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.3.9).

Comment: @JustLudo
I used jupyterlab.

Comment: @Airi it looks like the extension module was not built properly. Can you check that `libxml2`, `libxmlsec1` and `pkg-config` are installed (typically via Homebrew)? If yes, what does `otool -L $(python -c "from site import getsitepackages as f; print(f()[0])")/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so` output? Is `libxmlsec1.1.dylib` listed? Also, do you have the new M1 or the Intel chip in your Mac?

Comment: Another thing - can you reinstall with a verbose log and post it somewhere, e.g. on pastebin? You'd have to run `pip install xmlsec1 -vvv --no-cache-dir`, as `pip` has probably already cached the faulty wheel.

Comment: @hoefling
There is not libxmlsec1.1.dylib. I use apple M1.

Comment: @Airi looks like you have the same issue as in [#163](https://github.com/mehcode/python-xmlsec/issues/163). Unfortunately, I don't have access to Apple Silicon hardware right now, so I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @hoefling
I found that output below  when I put ```otool -L $(python -c "from site import getsitepackages as f; print(f()[0])")/xmlsec.cpython-38-darwin.so```

Output: ```/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libxmlsec1/1.2.31: 220 files, 6.2MB
==> Caveats```

Comment: @hoefling 
Plus, when I put ```this:pip install xmlsec1 -vvv --no-cache-dir```, I got this below error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xmlsec1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xmlsec1

Comment: Sorry, my fault - the command is of course `pip install xmlsec -vvv --no-cache-dir`